# Global Variable in Python cross module

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have two Python modules:

- `one.py`; and
- `two.py`

I want to change `X` global variable in `two.py`.Script `two.py` running. After  I run  `one.py`

***one.py***

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import two

def main():
 two.function("20")

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

***two.py***

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

X="10"
def main():
 while True:
  function()
 time.sleep(0.25)

def function(input="00"):
 if(input!="00"):
      global X
      X=input
      print "change"

 print X
if __name__=="__main__":
  main()
```

console:

```
sudo python two.py

10
10
10
10

after I run one.py  but no change in two.py
```

Comment: Why do you run `two.py` with `sudo`?

Comment: Well you'll be running `two.py` as a separate Python process than `one.py` so you can't really change global variables like that. You'll need some kind of inter-process communication.

Comment: Hi Tagc  inter-process communication is Thread ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> after I run one.py  but no change in two.py

What you're doing *dynamically* changes the variables. It doesn't re-write the files.

Which is in fact, what you might want to do.

`myfile.txt`

```
5
```

`reader.py`

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as fp:
    nb = int(fp.read())
    print(nb)
```

`writer.py`

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'w') as fp:
    fp.write('6')
```

Now, if you run `reader.py`, it'll output `5`. Then if you run `writer.py`, it'll output nothing, just replace the entire content of `myfile.txt` with `6`. And then, rerun `reader.py`, it'll output `6`, because the content of the file as changed. It works because, unlike your program that you run, the files' content doesn't depend of a process, it's "static".

Comment: It is Solutions Thank you